# Bash loop to gunzip file and remove file extension and file prefixes

Tags: string, bash, shell, command-line

I have several .vcf.gz files:

```
subset_file1.vcf.vcf.gz
subset_file2.vcf.vcf.gz
subset_file3.vcf.vcf.gz
```

I want to gunzip these file and rename them (remove `subset_` and redudant `.vcf` extension in one go and get these files:

```
file1.vcf
file2.vcf
file3.vcf
```

This is the script I have tried:

```
iFILES=/file/path/*.gz
for i in $iFILES;
do gunzip -k $i > /get/in/this/dir/"${i##*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to three operation at your output path name

1.remove the directory part

2.remove prefix `subset_`

3.remove redudant extension `.vcf`

It's hard to accomplish with only one command.

Following is a modification version. Be **CAREFUL** to try it. I didn't test it thorough in my computer.

```
for i in /file/path/*.gz;
do 
    # get the output file name
    o=$(echo ${i##*/} | sed 's/.*_\(.*\)\(\.[a-z]\{3\}\)\{2\}.*/\1\2/g')       
    gunzip -k $i > /get/in/this/dir/$o
done
```

Comment: I suggest changing the sed command to use the string "subset" explicitly (`s/subset_\(.*\)\(\.[a-z]\{3\}\)\{2\}.*/\1\2/g`) to avoid the greedy `.*` for filenames including an underscore.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. Or change to `sed 's/[^_]\+_\(.*\)\(\.[a-z]\{3\}\)\{2\}.*/\1\2/g'` move the first prefix